# Conditional label depending on the input of a custom function in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, ggplot2, dplyr

Suppose I have the following function:

```
  my_function <- function(date1, date2, variable, quota, monthly_business_days) {
    value <- deparse(substitute(variable))

    my_data %>%
      filter(between(DATE, ymd(date1), ymd(date2))) %>% 
      summarize(total = sum({{variable}})) %>%
      add_row(total = quota, .before = 1) %>% 
      rbind(.$total[[2]]/bizdays(date1, date2)*monthly_business_days) %>%
      mutate(indicator = if(value == 'UNITS') c("Quota (Units)", "Sales (Units)", "Forecast (Units)")
                   else c("Quota (USD)", "Sales (USD)", "Forecast (USD)")) %>% 
      mutate(indicator = as_factor(indicator)) %>% 
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(., 1))) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = indicator, y = total)) +
      geom_col(fill = "aquamarine3", color = "black") +
      geom_label(aes(label = total), size = 8) +
    if(value == UNITS) {
        labs(x = "", y = "Units") +
    } else if(value == SALES) {
        labs(x = "", y = "USD") +
    } else {
        labs(x = "", y = "") +
    }
      theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1)))
  }
```

I would like to include labels in my plot from ggplot2 depending on the function's input. Please bear in mind that this input is being used to select a specific column from "my_data" data frame. I'm not sure whether to use "variable" or "value". None of those seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
#Code
my_function <- function(date1, date2, variable, quota, monthly_business_days) {
  value <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  
  #Plot
  p <- my_data %>%
    filter(between(DATE, ymd(date1), ymd(date2))) %>% 
    summarize(total = sum({{variable}})) %>%
    add_row(total = quota, .before = 1) %>% 
    rbind(.$total[[2]]/bizdays(date1, date2)*monthly_business_days) %>%
    mutate(indicator = if(value == 'UNITS') c("Quota (Units)", "Sales (Units)", "Forecast (Units)")
           else c("Quota (USD)", "Sales (USD)", "Forecast (USD)")) %>% 
    mutate(indicator = as_factor(indicator)) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(., 1))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = indicator, y = total)) +
    geom_col(fill = "aquamarine3", color = "black") +
    geom_label(aes(label = total), size = 8)
  #Conditions  
  if(value == UNITS) {
      p <- p+labs(x = "", y = "Units") 
    } else if(value == SALES) {
      p <- p+labs(x = "", y = "USD")
    } else {
      p <- p+labs(x = "", y = "")
    }
  #Add
  p <- p+theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1)))
  
}
```

Comment: That's good actually, but I'm trying to have everything in one big chunk of code without having to create new variables such as p. Is that possible?

Comment: @caproki Technically p is not a variable, it is the plot object and you can add any element you want, as we did. I see that would be a good way to do what you want instead of getting complex things when trying to add all the code in one shot.

Comment: Thanks, that will work then. However, I had to put UNITS and SALES between quotes in the if/else part to get the desired result

Comment: @caproki Great! Yeah what you did is correct, good approach :)